# When the Limited Wish spell duplicates a spell, is the duplicated spell effect treated as that spell or as Limited Wish?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, wish

When the spell *limited wish* is used to duplicate a spell, is that effect the actual spell *or*, instead, is that effect *limited wish* reproducing the spell's effect?

The 7th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*limited wish*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/limitedWish.htm) [univ] (*PH* 248)

> lets you create nearly any type of effect. For example, a *limited wish* can do any of the following things.
>
> - Duplicate any sorcerer/wizard spell of 6th level or lower, provided the spell is not of a school prohibited to you.
> - Duplicate any other spell of 5th level or lower, provided the spell is not of a school prohibited to you.
> - Duplicate any sorcerer/wizard spell of 5th level or lower, even if it’s of a prohibited school.
> - Duplicate any other spell of 4th level or lower, even if it’s of a prohibited school.
>
> ...A duplicated spell allows saving throws and spell resistance as normal (but the save DC is for a 7th-level spell). When a *limited wish* duplicates a spell that has an XP cost, you must pay that cost or 300 XP, whichever is more. When a *limited wish* spell duplicates a spell with a material component that costs more than 1,000 gp, you must provide that component.

I know this *seems* like it would never matter, so here are some places where it does. (An answer may need to address the following sub-questions individually depending on how the answer tackles the main question.)

1. Can *limited wish* be used to duplicate the effect of the 4th-level Drd spell [*reincarnate*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/reincarnate.htm) [trans] (*PH* 270) so as to be the companion spell of the 6th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*contingency*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/contingency.htm) [evoc] (*PH* 213)? That is, the spell *reincarnate* can normally be a level 12 caster's *contingency*'s companion spell, but, as the companion spell's limited to a 6th-level or lower spell, a 7th-level *limited wish* duplicating the spell *reincarnate* may not be available as a *contingency*'s companion spell. *Note:* Related to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69334/8610).
2. Can *limited wish* be used to duplicate the effect of the 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*tongues*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/tongues.htm) [div] (*PH* 294) so that such an effect can be placed in a [*minor ring of spell storing*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/rings.htm#spellStoringMinor)? That is, the typical Sor/Wiz version of the spell *tongues* fits in a *minor ring of spell storing*, but a 7th-level *limited wish* duplicating the spell *tongues* may not.
3. Can *limited wish* be used to duplicate the effect of the 4th-level Clr spell [*imbue with spell ability*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/imbueWithSpellAbility.htm) [evoc] (*PH* 243) so as to meet the prerequisites of creating a [*minor ring of spell storing*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/rings.htm#spellStoringMinor)? The spell *imbue with spell ability* is a prerequisite for the creation of a *ring of spell storing*, but a *limited wish* duplicating the spell *imbue with spell ability* may not be a prerequisite for that item's creation.

(Note that even if 3 *is* possible, the caster should probably find a friendly cleric rather than (depending on the reading) spending 300 XP per day of crafting on *limited wish*es.)

Comment: Actually, this affects a lot of things - the most obvious example is bonuses from school specialization, which, depending on your prestige class could be a *huge* deal.

Comment: Also, *globe of invulnerability* effects are probably the most direct case where you would care.

Comment: Wondering if this affects counterspelling as well.  Probably another rabbit hole=)

Answer (score 10):

## No, but...

If you duplicate a spell effect and the save DC that comes out is for a 7th-level spell, then it seems to me that the effect you're getting is a 7th-level effect.  (And thus not suitable for *contingency*, *ring of spell storing*, etc.)

But Limited Wish also says it can "Produce any other effect whose power level is in line with the above effects".  It seems like you could just wish:

- "I wish that my contingency spell should get a casting of reincarnate plugged into it."
- "I wish that my ring of spell storing should get a tongues spell plugged into it."
- "I wish to meet the 'imbue with spell-like ability spell' prerequisite while magic item crafting today."

I think all these effects are "in line" with the original power of duplicating spell effects.

Answer (score 7):

When you cast Limited Wish, the spell you duplicate takes a 7th-level spell slot, although the spell effects are of a 6th level spell power or lower.

The way the catch-all effect line of limited wish reads, it looks like it RAI the spell duplicates the effects not the casting of the spell. You're casting Limited Wish and its effects are whatever you choose that is a 6th-level Spell in Power or lower effect. Spells just happens to already be ranked in terms of power and those four categories (Wizard spells, non-wizard spells, prohibited wizard spells, prohibited non-wizard spells) just outline how much more power creating those effects is with your Limited Wish.

1. You're gaining the Reincarnate effect, but not at the spell level of Reincarnate.
2. Limited Wish effects can't be stored in the Ring of Spell Storing for the same reason.
3. As per the [Magic Item Creation Rules](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm), normally, the spell needs to be known by the caster as a requirement, but...

   > Note that all items have prerequisites in their descriptions. These prerequisites must be met for the item to be created. Most of the time, they take the form of spells that must be known by the item’s creator (**although access through another magic item or spellcaster is allowed**).

This appears to me to mean that you just need the effect, not the casting of the spell, to create the item. What about using an existing Ring of spell-storing as a template for a new one, activating the ring to add the effect to the new one? The effect of the ring you're trying to make isn't as the spell, it's just a very related effect; you're not storing the spell itself in the ring as you would with a wand. For this reason, I'd argue that Limited Wish would work for this purpose.

Comment: "When you cast *limited wish*, the spell you duplicate takes a 7th-level spell slot, although the spell effects are of a 6th level spell." Can you unpack this? I'm unclear as to why it'd be a flat *6th-level* effect (cf. the save DC).

Comment: Quoted from the entry: "A duplicated spell allows saving throws and spell resistance as normal (but the save DC is for a 7th-level spell)." Although, you're probably wondering why I didn't specify "or lower". I'll correct that.