# What exactly is ignored in the "requirements" of a spell when Wishing for it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components, wish

One of the uses of the [*wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) spell is to emulate any spell of 8th level or lower "without meeting any requirements" of that spell. It is already clear from *wish*'s description that costly material components are to be discarded, but what about other requirements of a spell?

In general, what is considered a requirement of a spell for the purposes of *wish*?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83174/discussion-on-question-by-gael-l-what-exactly-is-ignored-in-the-requirements-o).

Comment: @Medix2 that question is closed as unclear and we should not close a question to another question that is closed when the current question does not have the same issue. Being that the other question is unclear it is even more dangerous since the entire problem was that it was unclear what the question actually was. So, not a duplicate that should be closed to.

Comment: Related on [What attributes are considered spell requirements](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130660/what-attributes-are-considered-spell-requirements/) and [Does casting Contingency with Wish allow you to pick a spell that you don't usually have access to as the contingent spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128055/does-casting-contingency-with-wish-allow-you-to-pick-a-spell-that-you-dont-usua?s=2|53.7080)

Comment: Related on  [If I use wish to duplicate a concentration spell does it still require concentration?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130648/if-i-use-wish-to-duplicate-a-concentration-spell-does-it-still-require-concentr)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Wish lets you ignore the **requirements** of:

1. providing components
2. providing the correct time casting
3. providing an appropriate spell slot
4. having that spell to be on your prepared or known spells list
5. having that spell be of an appropriate level or school

---

**Requirements**, unfortunately, is never really given a game term definition.
So as with all words that don't have a game term definition, we should attempt to use the standard english definition.

Using that, we can say that anything is a requirement **if it prevents you from casting the spell**.

So with that in mind, here's the justification:

**[Level] [School]** - If a spell is not normally of the right level or school for you, you cannot cast it. This is a "requirement".

**Casting Time: x** - If you do not spend the amount of time specified, you cannot cast it. This is a "requirement".

**Range: x** Having nothing in range does not actually prevent you from casting a spell (for example, [readying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87657/23970)) - it prevents you from targeting it. This is NOT a "requirement".

**Components: x, y, z (special)** - if you cannot provide the proper components, you cannot cast the spell. This is a "requirement".

**Duration: x** - duration has nothing to do with whether you're capable of casting a spell. This is NOT a "requirement".

**Concentration** - When casting a spell normally, you can choose not to maintain concentration. The spell will end, but you are not prevented from casting it. This is NOT a "requirement".

**Classes: x** - If a spell is not on your prepared or known spells, you cannot cast it. This is a "requirement".

**Description: [Effects]** - Effects can only take place after casting is completed. This is NOT a "requirement".

**Spell Slot** - If you cannot provide the right spell slot, you cannot cast a spell. This is a "requirement".

Specific features (in addition to Wish) can negate some or all of these requirements, *or even add requirements*: see Subtle Spell or Ritual Casting

Comment: Does point 4 encompass both Classes and LevelxSchool requirements? If so I would make that more clear.

Comment: Added point 5 to match up with the explanation text

Comment: I agree that this answers what is required to *cast* a spell, but *wish* says "You don't need to meet any requirements in that spell", which sounds both extremely broad and extremely vague. Can you expand on how you're interpreting this phrase to mean only casting requirements? (As opposed to e.g. concentration, which is not required for casting but is required to maintain the spell effect.)

Comment: +1 for noting that the rules don't really specify what a "requirement" is, and for then going ahead and defining it.

Comment: "Casting another spell that requires concentration. You lose concentration on a spell if you cast another spell that requires concentration. You can't concentrate on two spells at once." You may decide to not define concentration as a requirement, but the PHB does.

Answer (score 10):

## "Requirements" is not game term, so DMs must interpret.

The rules do not describe what "requirement" means: it's not a game term the way "attack" or "spell" are. This means that differing DMs may interpret what a requirement is in the context of [*wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) in slightly different ways.

However, as with all words that are not a game term, we can attempt to use the standard English definition. In this case: "a thing that is compulsory; a necessary condition."

We should try to contextualize that generic definition. When *wish* is used to duplicate a spell, "the spell simply takes effect". With this in mind I believe that **"any condition you normally must satisfy for a spell to take effect" is a requirement that *wish* ignores**.

## Examples

The **spell's effect** is **not** a requirement. Rather, it is what *wish* duplicates.

**Casting time** is a requirement which wish ignores, because [you normally must spend a certain amount of time casting for a spell to take effect](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingTime).

**Components** are requirements which wish ignores, because [you normally must provide/handle/perform components for a spell to take effect](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#Components).

**Duration** is **not** a requirement, because [it only defines how long the spell effect lasts](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#Duration). The same is true for **concentration**, it only defines how long the spell effect lasts.

**Having the spell firmly fixed in mind** is a requirement which wish ignores, because [you normally must learn or prepare a spell to cast it](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#KnownandPreparedSpells). This goes along with the fact that *wish* explicitly "duplicate[s] *any* other spell of 8th level or lower".

**Spell slots** are requirements which wish ignores, because [you normally must expend a spell slot for a spell to take effect](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#SpellSlots).

The **spell's level** is **not** a requirement, because [it just indicates how powerful the spell is](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#SpellLevel). Moreover, *wish* explicitly limits you to "spell[s] of 8th level or lower", so either way *wish* does not ignore the spell's level.

The **spell's school** is **not** a requirement. Rather it is a description of the spell's effect.

**Targeting restrictions** are requirements which *wish* ignores<sup>1</sup>, because [you normally must target something for the spell to take effect](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#Targets). This includes rules for [range](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#Range) and other requirements described in the spell, such as sight and shared language.
Rules for a [clear path to the target](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#AClearPathtotheTarget) are more nuanced: AoE spells take effect even if the target is behind total cover, so a clear path to the target is **not** a requirement for AoE spells. However, it is still a requirement for other spells.

---

1. I recommend ruling that spells duplicated by *wish* must still meet the targeting rules (especially range), because being able to target anyone wherever they are once a day, can seriously break a campaign.

---

This answer is based in part on [a different answer by Speedkat](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/130686/42865).

Comment: I would argue that targeting rules are not requirements. You can still cast a spell on an invalid target, but it will have a different effect than your probably intended. For example, *hold person* can be cast on a non-humanoid, it just has no effect. Similarly, a *fireball* can be aimed at a point behind a wall, but then the effect is that the fireball impacts the wall and explodes at the point of impact, instead of exploding at the point where the caster targeted. You can even cast a spell without targeting anything (e.g. readying a spell and then choosing not to release it).

Comment: @RyanThompson "A typical spell **requires you to pick one or more targets to be affected by the spell's magic**". You can cast *hold person* and pick no one and in that case no effect happens. However, wish duplicates the effect, not the casting, hence targeting is a prerequisite for duplicating the effect of *hold person*. I think you might be right about *fireball* though.

Comment: @Ruse The rules for concentration also use the word "require", but you say concentration is not considered a requirement.

Comment: @RyanThompson that is an example of why "requirement" cannot be interpreted as strictly and blindly as a game term. "Some spells require you to maintain concentration **in order to keep their magic active**" not "in order for the spell to take effect". If you choose not to maintain concentration, the effect just ends as soon as it takes effect, but it still takes effect, hence concentration is not a requirement that *wish* ignores.

Answer (score 8):

*Wish* can be cast to emulate spells the caster normally wouldn't be able to cast; i.e., not in their spellbook if they're a Wizard, Cleric Only Spell for non-Cleric, etc.   *Any spell* means what it says: *any* spell.

What is a spell?  [A spell is a spell on a spell list](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131495/what-counts-as-a-spell) that creates a magical effect.

> By simply speaking aloud (components are replaced by simply speaking
>   aloud) ... duplicate any other spell of 8th level or lower. You
>   don’t need  to meet any requirements in that spell, including costly
>   components. The spell simply takes effect.  (wish, spell description, PHB)

No mention is made of casting time; the text of the *wish* spell casting time is "1 action" and "by simply speaking aloud" the desired spell "simply takes effect."

Just say it, and it takes effect.

What constraints on a spell might be in play when used like this?  Since it *duplicates* a given spell, you would expect the *duplicated* spell cast by *wish* to have the same range and area of effect.    Nowhere does *wish* indicate that it changes a spell when cast this way.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour] for a quick intro to how we do things around here.  This answer looks like it's pointing in the right direction, but could be improved with some rules citations.  In addition, are there other sorts of requirements (besides "what class list it came from") that should be addressed?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your answer could do with some fleshing out and support with evidence. Wish can ignore spell requirements but the question is asking is what all can count for that. Yes class requirements are one of those, but what about casting time or duration? My recommendation would be to delete you answer while you make edits to it in this case so that you don't attract downvotes unnecessarily. Or just keep it deleted if you don't intend to improve it.

Comment: I have added some rules text and a supporting point as an example of what rubiksmoose is referring to.  If you like the edit, fine.  If not, please edit it again so that it is more to your liking.  Welcome.

Comment: This is actually kinda funny.  Read through the edits, the original answer was about one sentence long, the rest was added in by @KorvinStarmast.  Nice work, KS!

Comment: @DanielZastoupil The answer as originally posed was correct, but sometimes I have found that it is useful to demonstrate what we prefer in terms of supported answers.  (One never really stops being an instructor, I guess ...)

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the updates and a demonstration. I'll flesh it out more next time!

Comment: Welcome, glad that you have joined us.  Look forward to your future contributions.

Answer (score 5):

#### “Requirements” refers to everything necessary for casting the spell that *is not an effect of the spell*.

First, consider the relevant effect of *wish*:

> The basic use of this spell is to *duplicate* any other spell of 8th level or lower. You don't need to meet any requirements in that spell, including costly components. The spell simply takes effect.

“Duplicate” here indicates that *wish* produces exactly the effect of the duplicated spell. Duplicating a spell with *wish* cannot do anything except for producing an exact duplicate of the spell’s effect. If, hypothetically, we *change* any portion of the spell’s effect, we are not *duplicating* that spell. This, of course, begs the question “what exactly is a spell’s effect?” Fortunately, the rules tell us exactly what a spell’s effect is:

> Each spell description in Chapter 11 begins with a block of information, including the spell’s name, level, school of magic, casting time, range, components, and duration. *The rest of a spell entry describes the spell’s effect.*

The “rest of a spell entry” here refers to the block of text that follows “ the spell’s name, level, school of magic, casting time, range, components, and duration.” Ergo, duplicating a spell with *wish* cannot change *anything* in this block of text, since this block of text is exactly the spell’s effect that is duplicated.

So we conclude that the requirements that are ignored by *wish* are anything else that is usually necessary for *casting* the spell that is not contained in this block of text.

Comment: By association, I presume some parts of the spell effect that rely on requirements (Instant Summons for example) are still required?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Yeah, I think that’s the right take.

Answer (score 1):

### The *Player's Handbook* mentions spell "requirements".

Under ["Chapter 10: Spellcasting"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting), the PHB and Basic Rules list parts of the spells and mention requirements.

[Casting Time](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingTime) (p. 202):

> Most spells **require** a single action to cast, but some spells require a bonus action, a reaction, or much more time to cast.

[Components](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Components) (p. 203):

> A spell’s components are the physical **requirements** you must meet in order to cast it.

[Concentration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Concentration) (p. 203):

> Some spells **require** you to maintain concentration in order to keep their magic active.

[Targets](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Targets) (p. 204):

> A typical spell **requires** you to pick one or more targets to be affected by the spell’s magic.

and [Attack Rolls](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#AttackRolls) (p. 205):

> Some spells **require** the caster to make an attack roll to determine whether the spell effect hits the intended target.

Therefore, the casting time of the recreated spell becomes the 1 action of *wish*. Components become the verbal component of *wish*. Spells that normally require concentration automatically last their full duration without concentration and attack spells (not area effect spells) automatically hit.

The only vagueness up for DM discretion and discussion that I really see is "targets".

I should note that [range](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Range) isn't a "requirement" and stays the same, so spells with a range of Self still only target or originate from you.