# Is target species or creature type a 'requirement' when duplicating a spell with Wish?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wish

As the question asks (above): is the creature's type one of the 'requirements' when casting a wish spell? If so, a *Wish* spell would have greater flexibility &/or utility.

This may have been answered (generally-partially) here in Stack Exchange (?): a *Wish* 'requirement' is suggested to be [anything that prevents you from casting a spell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131695/what-exactly-is-ignored-in-the-requirements-of-a-spell-when-wishing-for-it). If this question is judged as a repeat question, apologies in advance. That aside, if creature-type qualifies as something that prevents the casting of a *Wish* spell ('case in point'), it also counts as argument-precedent and is thus useful for this answer.

**Examples of using non-stress *Wish* when a creature's species-type is a 'requirement':**

- *Reincarnation & Cloning* of non-humanoids becomes possible via basic *Wish* spells (such as the reincarnation of fae (like Pixies) or the cloning of a dragon)
- 4th level *Polymorph* may be able to turn a creature into something other than a 'beast', not requiring the *Wish* spell to mimic the 9th level *True Polymorph* (True Poly is NOT 8th level or lower / would otherwise NOT work).
- 'Heals' may work on certain undead otherwise prohibited - or even rapid repair of *Simulacra*. In this example a *Simulacrum* specifically states they need (expensive / time consuming) repairs to be fixed and heals do not work. If one uses a *Wish* to cast a heal spell it could work *but only if the creature's type (Simulacrum) is considered a 'requirement'.

Do note that these are three **examples** only / not an extensive list.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What exactly is ignored in the "requirements" of a spell when Wishing for it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/131695)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### If you change the spell language, it's not the spell

The standard use of *wish* states (PHB, 288):

> The basic use of this spell is to duplicate any other spell of 8th level or lower.

Therefore by using *wish* to duplicate the casting of a spell of 8th level or lower, you will avoid stress.

However, if you change the spells, then you simply aren't casting that spell. You are no longer duplicating that spell, and instead you are now casting *something different and special that isn't that original spell*.

This means that there is stress. If you want to avoid the stress, just avoid going outside the normal *wish* guidelines.

Comment: I like this answer, and think it's correct, but I think its statement is a little too broad: after all, replicating the effects of the spell *Planar Binding* with *Wish* has shortened the casting time from an hour to 1 action, and removed the material and somatic components. Both these things could be seen to have "change[d] the spell". Since *Wish* states "You don’t need to meet any requirements in that spell, including costly components", I think it would be really helpful to say how we know that components and casting time are "requirements," but valid-target-type is something more.

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme Those are components/requirements, not the spell language. Or, that's what I'm trying to say!